# Can't call method "capture2" on unblessed reference

Tags: perl, unix, ssh, openssh

```
if($var ==1){
    function($host);}
#OTHER PROCESSING   
#***
#****
# ****  
$hostForSsh =$host;
my $whatever ="xyz"
my $something= $ssh->capture2(qq(/user/somePlace $whatever) );#--line A
```

The function above runs perfectly when value of $var passed is 1 but gives
Can't call method "capture2" on unblessed reference -->error on line A if $var =0.

Comment: Not enough detail here to answer. We need to know where `$ssh` is coming from. My guess would be it's not being instantiated correctly.

Comment: Object of ssh is being passed to the function as $ssh. it was working completely fine until the $var =1 loop was introduced. So ow, it works fine if loop is being entered else it gives the error

Comment: Still can't answer without the rest of the code.

Comment: The error is saying that you are treating `$ssh` as an object, it's actually, just a plain ("unblessed") object. Try printing `ref $ssh` and you'll see it's not an object. As @Sobrique says, you'll need to trace where `$ssh` comes from and how it gets into that state.

Comment: Thank you so much for that elaborate description. was able to identify the actual error because of the direction ur answer provided @DaveCross and @Sobrique!!

Cheerzz!!

Answer (score -2):

Solved! Problem was in $ssh only! Actually, I forgot to pass the $ssh object in the particular function and i did not notice this as many arguments were being passed to the function.

Comment: As it stands, this isn't a very useful answer. It would be great if you could take the time to write up what the problem was in a bit more detail.

Comment: Please remember that, although it may not feel that way, the primary purpose of a Stack Overflow page is to help the hundreds of people with a similar problem who come across your question. Please show your gratitude for the help you have received by writing up a solution that will help those people.

Comment: My bad @DaveCross
Actually, I forgot to pass the $ssh object in the particular function and id id not notice this as many arguments were being passed to the function. So, honestly, I thought that it would very silly to specify such a silly solution. Will edit immediately..

Comment: my bad @Borodin
Actually, I forgot to pass the $ssh object in the particular function and id id not notice this as many arguments were being passed to the function. So, honestly, I thought that it would very silly to specify such a silly solution. Will edit immediately..